# how can 2 Azure function deployment slots, be available at the same time?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

I asked this question to ChatGPT and it says yes.
But when I deploy to the DEV slot, the dev URL works but when I swap, the production URL works but the DEV slot does not even have a function.

Maybe I am deploying with VS2022 wrong?
I need to be able to serve the same function with 4 different configuration items to my testing users and the production users, all the time.
Is "deployment slots" even the right use case for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Deployment slots are live apps with their own hostnames. For example, if the app's host name is functionappname.azurewebsites.net and if this app has a slot called dev, then the slot will have the site name functionappname-dev.azurewebsites.net. They will be available all the time. Clients can send requests to these sites.

During swap operation, App content and configurations elements are swapped. In your case, it appears that you are having functions only in one slot so when you swap, the other slot is empty. If you have functions in both the slots, they can work independently with different host names.

Please note that, for consumption plan you can create only one deployment slot. Dedicated and premium plan doesnt have any limitations on the number of slots.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-deployment-slots#swap-operations

Comment: Thank you. In my case I deployed same code to the 2 slots and did not swap so both worked with their assigned environment variables. Works fine